# Zend Framework 1.11, Doctrine2 - How to test controllers without flushing to the database

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, controller, phpunit

I have doctrine2 setup with ZF 1.11, I am having difficulty learning the best way to unit test controllers. I would like to be able to test actions in controllers without writing to the database within my unit tests however I am finding it impossible to actually do so.

For example say I have the following hypothetical action within my controller.

```
public function redirectUserAction() {
    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
    $em = $registry->entitymanager;
    $user = $em->getRepository('Application_Model_User')
               ->findOneBy(array('email' => 'test@test.com'));
    if(is_object($user)) {
        $this->_redirect('/');
    }
}
```

I want to test that if there is a user available with the email address test@test.com it will redirect to / so at the moment I have the following test.

```
public function testUserAvaliableShouldRedirectIndex() {
    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
    $em = $registry->entitymanager;
    $user = new Application_Model_User();
    $user->setEmail('test@test.com');
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
    $this->dispatch('/index/redirect-user');
    $this->assertRedirectTo('/'); 
    $em->remove($user);
    $em->flush(); 
}
```

This seems to me like a very messy way of writing tests. I was under the impression that with doctrine I wouldn't need to actually flush to the database because my objects would be stored in the persistence layer but at the moment my tests fail without flushing.

If anyone knows a better way I could write tests or can help me see where I am going wrong I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating and deleting the user in `testUserAvaliableShouldRedirectIndex()` you could use `setUp()` and `tearDown()` to create and delete the user. This way you can use that user throughout all actions that expect an existing user, like your `redirectUserAction()`, `loginAction()`, etc. instead of having to do what you currently do for each of these actions.

Comment: Thanks, I think that would help but I am wondering if it's possible to setup the tests without actually writing data to the database. My understanding is that functionally testing the controllers shouldn't involve writing to the database but I may be wrong.

Comment: @user1070377: You'd have to mock the entity manager. My understanding is that it's so cumbersome to do, that it's more common to simply use a separate db for your testing environment and fixtures in setUp/tearDown to control the state of that test db.

Comment: Sorry this should be a post but I haven't got a good reputation yet. I decided to go with using the setup and tear down methods but to use doctrine transactions to keep the database in a clean state.

    public function setUp() {
        $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
        parent::setUp();    
        $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
        $this->_em = $registry->entitymanager;
        $this->_em->beginTransaction();
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        $this->_em->rollBack();
    }